# Get all positive integral solutions for a linear equation with different coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I need a solution for $x + 2y + 3z = 1000$; here $1000$ is a variable and need to get answer in terms of '$n$' i.e. I need a formula that solves for $x + 2y + 3z = n$
I know I can apply the solution for the $x_1 + x_2 +x_3 = k$ ,  $ n+k−1 \choose {k−1}$ but then I will have to convert all coefficients to $6$ which would generate $36$ cases. Does anyone have any other idea ?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that you're looking for positive integer solutions to $x+2y+3z=n$, for general $n$?

There are lots of ways to do this, depending on what techniques you know and understand.  If you can give us a bit more context, I'm sure somebody will be happy to help in a way that's useful to you.

Comment: @NickPeterson I understand the combinatorial solution, but if you have any other solution, please tell, I'll read all the books and try to understand it. Have added more details in the question.

Comment: Your equation $x+2y+3z=n$ is a Frobenius equation. The number of solutions for $n=1000$ is  $83667$ non negative triplets.

Comment: See https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/14375587.pdf
The number of solutions of $x+2y+3z=n$ is $S(n)=\frac{1}{72} \left(-12 n^2+18 n^2 \cos (2 \pi  n)-84 n+8 \sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{3}\right)+\\108 n \cos (2 \pi  n)-8 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{3}\right)-9 \cos (\pi  n)+153 \cos (2 \pi  n)-136\right)$.

Comment: @Raffaele Thanks for this paper, this is a life saver, just 1 question, the solution you mentioned is different from what is said in the paper - N(1,2,3;b)=1/12b^2+1/2b+47/72+(−1)^b/8+2/9cos2/3bπ  this is on page 9 in the pdf

Comment: Actually I got it in another way. My version can be simplified. The results are the same, tho

Comment: @Raffaele on using the paper's equation I am getting fractional answer. For example I tried for n = 4 and got 5.32...  whereas the actual answer is 5. Do I need to take a floor of this equation for the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the series:
$$
E = (1+T+T^2+T^3+\dots)(1+T^2+T^4+T^6+\dots)(1+T^3+T^6+T^9+\dots)
\\
=
\left(\sum_{x\ge 0}T^x\right)
\left(\sum_{y\ge 0}T^{2y}\right)
\left(\sum_{z\ge 0}T^{3z}\right)\ .
$$
Then the coefficient of $T^n$ in this series is the needed number.
So it remains to write $E$ as a power series. The partial fraction decomposition of
$$
E
=
\frac 1{1-T}\cdot
\frac 1{1-T^2}\cdot
\frac 1{1-T^3}
=
\frac 1{(1-T)^3}\cdot
\frac 1{1+T}\cdot
\frac 1{1+uT}\cdot
\frac 1{1+u^2T}
$$
is
$$
E=
\frac 19\cdot\left(\frac 1{1-uT}+\frac 1{1-u^2T}\right)
+
\frac 18\cdot\frac 1{1+T}
+
\frac {17}{72}\cdot\frac 1{1-T}
+
\frac 14\cdot\frac 1{(1-T)^2}
+
\frac 16\cdot\frac 1{(1-T)^3}
\ .
$$
Here, $u,u^2$ are the two primitive third roots of unity, $(-1\pm i\sqrt 3)/2$.
The first term is periodic with period $3$. We use $u^k+u^{2k}=u+u^2=-1$ for $k$ not a multiple of $3$, and of course $u^k+u^{2k}=1+1=2$ else. So it is $\frac 19(2-T-T^2+2T^3-T^4-T^5+2T^6-\dots)$. So instead of using trigonometric functions, just use the periodic pattern $2, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1, 2,\dots$

The second term is $\frac 18(1-T+T^2-T^3+\dots)$. Geometric series.

The third term is also a geometric series.

Then we use (binomial series)
$1/(1-T)^2=1+2T+3T^2+4T^3+5T^4+\dots+\binom{n+1}1T^n+\dots$

and
$1/(1-T)^3=1+3T+6T^2+10T^3+15T^4+\dots+\binom{n+2}2T^n+\dots$ .

Now it is easy to collect the terms in degree $n$. For instance, for $n=1000$ we get
$$
-\frac 19+\frac 18+\frac {17}{72}+\frac 14\binom{1001}1+\frac 16\binom{1002}2
=
83834.
$$

---

Now let us re-read the OP, "positive integral solutions" may mean triples $(x,y,z)$ where each component is $>0$. (So all three components are positive.) Then the same has to be done for
$$
F = (T+T^2+T^3+\dots)(T^2+T^4+T^6+\dots)(T^3+T^6+T^9+\dots) = T^6E
\ .
$$
The coefficient in degree $1000$ in $F$ corresponds to the coefficient in degree $1000-6$ in $E$. This coefficient is
$$
-\frac 19+\frac 18+\frac {17}{72}+\frac 14\binom{995}1+\frac 16\binom{996}2
=
82834.
$$